# I have 87% packet loss on a direct connection?

Tags: dell-poweredge

Bought a dell r720.

Trying to install proxmox on it. Proxmox is a VM host.

I plugged an Ethernet cable into the NIC on the r720 and my NIC on my desktop.

Desktop is 10.12.1.18. Proxmox is 10.12.1.2.

When I ping proxmox, I get 25% packet loss.

When I ping desktop from proxmox, I get 89% packet loss. How am I losing packets on a direct connection?

I tried two Ethernet cables.

I'm assuming it's the NIC, but I want to believe it isn't the NIC. When I installed proxmox onto the r720 I plugged my modem router Combo into it and during the IP config part of the installation, it was able to be leased an IP address and knew my location based on IP.  So I don't think the NIC is bad.

Comment: try another NIC. Also, try another OS. Sometimes with issues like this its handy to actually pin down each possible element

Comment: That's my last resort since I don't have a NIC right now